# unable to delete specfic mySQL record through python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

creating and viewing records is working well but when is use the bookreturned function it shows mySQL syntax error someone help!

````
    r=input("please provide the Addmission number of the student")
    query=("delete from class_12 where roll_no=%s")
    cmd.execute(query,r)
    cmd.execute("commit")

    ```
````

Comment: First, I am not sure why you have have a useless parenthesis around your query expression. Second, try: `cursor.execute(query, (r,))` where `cursor` is your cursor object (if `cmd` is not it) followed by `cnx.commit()` where `cnx` is your connection object.

Comment: adding the the comma(,) after r in the cmd.execute() statement did the work! Can you tell me it's significance?

Comment: The second argument to `execute` must be a `list` or `tuple` of parameters. Your SQL had one `%s` parameter fulfilled by `r`, so you needed to pass either a list `[r]` or  a tuple `(r,)`. Note that `(r)` is not a tuple; it is just a parenthesized expression, that is you must add that comma to make sure it is considered a tuple.